# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError: Script execution failed. An open modal dialog blocked the operation

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have noticed something strange. If I use Firefox, this works fine:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
# => true 

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
# => #<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x..fc3c6738535bdb898 browser=:firefox> 

driver.execute_script "window.alert('text');"
# => "text"
```

Alert popup opens.

If I do the same with Chrome, the alert popup opens, but I get an exception:

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
# => #<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x47f3180ec45394e8 browser=:chrome> 

driver.execute_script "window.alert('text');"
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError: Script execution failed. Script: window.alert('text');;
 An open modal dialog blocked the operation
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@gretel/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@gretel/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@gretel/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@gretel/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@gretel/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:64:in `request'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@gretel/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@gretel/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:590:in `raw_execute'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@gretel/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:568:in `execute'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@gretel/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:314:in `executeScript'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@gretel/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:209:in `execute_script'
    from (irb):14
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Environment:

- Mac OS X 10.7.3
- Firefox 10.0.2
- Chrome 17.0.963.56
- chromedriver_mac_18.0.1022.0
- Ruby ruby 1.9.2p290
- selenium-webdriver 2.19.0

Comment: Why would you want to trigger an alert through execute_script? This is considered undefined behaviour in WebDriver, so it's no surprise the drivers behave differently.

Comment: @jarib: It was just the easiest way of creating the popup. Are you saying it would behave differently if the alert was triggered by clicking a button on the page (or something like that)? Let me try that...

Comment: @jarib: Really, if the alert is triggered by the page, there is no exception in either Chrome or Firefox. Add your comment as an answer and I will accept it. :)

Comment: please clerify this question more detailed.

Comment: I must wuth WebDriver click "accept" in this dialog. how?

Answer (score 0):

Try it again as below with chromedriver.
The example for Java:

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.executeAsyncScript("arguments[0](); alert('Hello')");
try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```